# Get selected value of <select> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to get the value of `<select>` tags which is kind of a simple task. I have done it several time before but it looks wired no to work this time.

My select tag is as following:

```
<select id="tshirt['+$(this)[0].id+'][size]" style="width: 55px;" name=tshirt['+$(this)[0].id+'][size]">
    <option value="small">S</option>
    <option value="medium" selected="selected">M</option>
    <option value="large">L</option>
    <option value="xlarge">XL</option>
</select>
```

I tried to retrieve the selected element as following

```
$('#tshirt['+id+'][size] :selected').text()
$('select #tshirt['+id+'][size]').val()
$('#tshirt['+id+'][size]').children("option").filter(":selected").text()
```

I always get either undefined or `[]` or `""`. Any suggestions on how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS selectors, `#tshirt[foo]` does not mean "match the element with id `tshirt[foo]`. It means "match the element with id `tshirt` that has <invalid condition>".

To avoid this problem, restrict yourself to ids that don't contains CSS metacharacters or escape the metacharacters.

```
$('#tshirt\\['+id+'\\]\\[size\\] :selected')
```

Tested with the following:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<select id="tshirt[foo][size]" style="width: 55px;" name="tshirt[foo][size]">
    <option value="small">S</option>
    <option value="medium" selected="selected">M</option>
    <option value="large">L</option>
    <option value="xlarge">XL</option>
</select>
<script>
   var id = "foo";
   var rs = $('#tshirt\\['+id+'\\]\\[size\\] :selected');
   alert("size = " + rs.size());
   rs.each(function(i, ele){ alert("value = " + ele.value); });
</script>
```